# Why is my app ranking so low in the Play Store when I type the exact name?

Tags: android, search, google-play

The app was published about a month ago, and when I do a search for the exact name of the app Turbo Verse it ranks very low 25th at the highest, currently its #92.

I understand the basic SEO rules for the play store (downloads, rankings, compatibility etc.) but I feel this is an anomaly because this is the only app in the entire store that contains the words Turbo and Verse in the title and I can see no reason why it shouldnt be ranked very high for the exact name.

I was thinking it may have something to with the manifest so I will post it below, I have 18 reviews, mostly positive and over 100 downloads.

The full name of the App as it appears in the store is: Turbo Verse KJV - Bible Memory  but I am only typing in the first part: Turbo Verse, but when I type the whole name into the search its still ranking about 9 or 10th

I would really appreciate any advice, I am a new developer and I would like to learn from my mistakes.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.turboverse.scripturememory"
   android:versionCode="2"
   android:versionName="1.01" >


   <uses-sdk
       android:minSdkVersion="10"
       android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

   <application
       android:allowBackup="true"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
       android:description="@string/appDescription"
        >
       <activity
           android:name="com.turboverse.scripturememory.MainActivity"
           android:label="@string/app_name"
           android:screenOrientation="portrait"
           android:launchMode="singleTop" >
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
       </activity>
       <activity android:name=".RequestVerse" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
       <activity android:name=".ByReferenceBookList" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
       <activity android:name=".ByTopicList" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
       <activity android:name=".Chapters" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
       <activity android:name=".Verses" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
       <activity android:name=".PlayVerse" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
       <activity android:name=".MyVersesList" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
       <activity android:name=".ChapterVerses" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
       <activity android:name=".UpdateDownloadVerses" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
       <service android:name=".TurboVerseService" />
   </application>
   <!-- application android:name="GlobalObjects" android:label="@string/app_name" /-->
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission> 
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"><group gid="media_rw"></group></uses-permission>


   <supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
                     android:smallScreens="true"
                     android:normalScreens="true"
                     android:largeScreens="true"
                     android:xlargeScreens="true"
                     android:anyDensity="true" />


</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

The google algorithm is very intelligent you are getting your app in 25th ranking because algorithm search for the keyword in all categories and push the apps which has searched keyword in there name, high downloads and ratings to top.
Because algorithm thinks from the user prospective it has to return all the type of apps in different categories because it doent knw what actually user is searching for.

**Example**:- If user is searching for a recorder which capture voice and He/She search for **"Recorder"** basically top apps will be Recorder keyword in there name and high downloads and rating from different categories also.(Check all the top 20 apps).
This above search (Recorder) results include apps like **Voice Recorder, Call Recorder, Screen Recorder** so now this makes sense because algorithm doesnt know what actually user is searching for thats why it gives the results like that.

So thats why your app is ranking low when you search for keyword which is part of your app name. (If you search for you app name fully it should come first if it contains a unique name as you mentioned it should not be common keywords "Recorder").

Hope this answer will help many people to understand App store optimization.